# Bypassing router's DNS settings not working

Tags: linux, windows, networking, router, dns

From researching around the web, I found out how you are able to bypass the DNS settings that are configured on the router by naming the DNS servers you want to use on your PC. Supposedly, the PC DNS settings override the router's DNS settings by using Port 53. Problem is, my PC settings aren't overriding the router's at all.

I have tried configuring my DNS settings from Windows and Linux and yet I still get to the same problem.

The router is a Netgear WNR2000v3.

The methods I have tried are listed here: [WikiHow](http://www.wikihow.com/Bypass-OpenDNS-Internet-Security)

Comment: from an elevated command prompt, run `ipconfig /all` and note the DNS servers listed. are they the ones you configured statically, or those that the router passes out? if you reboot or run `ipconfig /flushdns` does the address resolve against your non-openDNS servers?

Comment: @FrankThomas When I run 'ipconfig /all' I get the ones that I statically typed and when i run 'ipconfig /flushdns' the DNS servers stay the same.

Comment: well, after running flush, the servers don't change, but the queries to DNS that you make might. try going to the site that OpenDNS was blocking and see if it resolves now. Windows caches DNS responses, so even if you change the server addresses, it will keep serving up the same response if you ask it to resolve the same address, until you reboot or the cache is cleared. then it will check with the configured servers to get the response.

Comment: I am still being blocked even after I flush the cache.  But the servers that I statically typed in are still there when I type `ipconfig /all`

Comment: if you type 'nslookup www.thesiteyouwanttogoto.xxx' does it resolve the address differantly, or is it still the opendns block page's IP? if it is, try powercycling the router. it may have cached content or the dns resolution. your router's manual doesn't provide any guidance on advanced dns features like caching or masquerading, so I don't know if thats because they are undocumented or just aren't implemented.

Comment: you can also try clearing the browser cache. it is possible the browser has cached the block page, and just keeps serving it back up to you.

Comment: I will have to try restarting the router and see if that works.  I tried clearing the browser cache as well and that didn't work.  When I used `nslookup` it just gave me the ip address of opendns's block page.